# NSUserDefaults Multi Value is nil

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults, userdefaults

Can somebody tell me, why I get nil, if I query

```
let stage = UserDefaults.standard.dictionary(forKey: "stageSelection")
```

my UserDefaults? There is a default vaule and I also changed the value in the settings. The settings screen is working fine - my problem is that I cannot query the selected value.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're querying for a dictionary value, but there's only a String stored in `UserDefaults`.

Use `let stage = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "stageSelection")`

Comment: let stage =  UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "stageSelection") still returns nil

Comment: That's to be expected until you either set a new value, or register a default using `UserDefaults.standard.register(defaults: ["stageSelection": "prod"])`. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9181544/setting-bundle-default-value-wont-set